# ERROR TypeError: this.userList is not iterable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I've been looking for similar issues but couldn't understand what my problem is. I am a rookie with Angular.

I am calling the `service.getUsers()`. And getting data successfully. But I've noticed that `this.userList` is `undefined` when I was debugging the code (shown on the image). My problem is I can't iterate `userList` it says `ERROR TypeError: this.userList is not iterable`

But on HTML I am using the `userList` as a resource to my table. I can see the data that I am getting from DB. So how am I seeing that data if it's undefined and not iterable? I need to use `userList` for loop in the same class.

[image]

```js
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(data => { this.userList = data; });

testFunction() {
  for (let user of this.userList) {
    this.selectedUserList.push(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: you have clearly said that ` this.userList is "undefined"` ...! ., so issue is with your api/service, please check that

Comment: Please avoid images when adding code-snippets, instead post them as raw text, so everybody can copy. If posting images then embed them by putting an exclamation mark before the markdown-link: `![showing debug of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOqXU.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I figured it out.

```
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(data=>{this.userList=data; console.log(data); this.testFunction();});
```

I called the function within the subscribe worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you are working in react. So sometimes you got this error because you want data array came from server to save in useState variable. And then that useState variable you used to show data on frontend.

Example Problem:

```
const {
    data: timetable_record,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useQuery("timetable", () => apiMiddleware("admin/timetable/timetable"));


  const [timetable, setTimetable] = useState(timetable_record);
```

So when you show data using timetable variable you got iteration error.

Solution:

```
const {
    data: timetable_record,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useQuery("timetable", () => apiMiddleware("admin/timetable/timetable"));

  console.log(timetable_record);

  const [timetable, setTimetable] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (timetable_record) {
      setTimetable(timetable_record);
    }
  }, [timetable_record]);
```

By doing this, useEffect function assign data to useState variable when there is data in it after loading.

Comment: No brother. I am working on my project and got this issue. So then I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the testFunction() after subscribing to the data, then you will not get this.userList as undefined. But otherwise you will.

This is because getUsers() return an observable, (since you are subscribing to it) and observables are asynchronous. So by the time getUsers() finishes executing and returns data, which inturn gets assigned to this.userList, the control has already reached the testFunction(). Since the former function hasn't returned yet, the variable this.userList will definitely be undefined.

```
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
  this.userList = data;
  this.testFunction();
});


testFunction() {
  for (let user of this.userList) {
    this.selectedUserList.push(user);
  }
}
```